# Relate Structure variables?

Tags: c++, variables, struct

I have a structure that I would like to make the variables related to each other. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
struct RSI
{
     int RSI;
     int ESI = RSI & 0x1F;
     int SI = ESI & 0x0F;
     int SIL = SI & 0x08;
};
```

Is there a way to do this in C, without having to create functions to modify the variables?

Comment: The title and tags say C++, but the body of the question says C: which is it?

Comment: And notice that the answer differs for C and C++. In C, it’s flat out not possible. In C++, it is.

Comment: In principle, a platform's ABI may provide enough definition to how structures and unions are laid out for you to be able to do something like your example at least to the byte level (however, note that you have ESI as a 5-bit variable, rather than the 32 that the name seems to imply) However, this isn't defined by the C or C++ standards.

Comment: @KonradRudolph C++ has getters/setters now?

Comment: @Random832 No but it has classes, operator overloading and in particular conversion operator overloading, which can be used here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you would need to define functions to do that.

In C++, you could of course encapsulate the details:

```
struct RSI
{
private:
    int rsi;

public:
    RSI(int rsi) : rsi(rsi) {}

    int getRSI() const { return rsi; }
    int getESI() const { return getRSI() & 0x1F; }
    int getSI()  const { return getESI() & 0x0F; }
    int getSIL() const { return getSI()  & 0x08; }
};
```

Comment: Your answer “no” applies to C but your code shows C++ where this would actually be possible (not that I’d generally advise it). Which is it?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I'm saying it's not possible without functions, but that in C++, the details can be somewhat encapsulated.

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case you can write:

```
union RSI_t
{
    int RSI;
    int ESI : 5;
    int SI : 4;
    int SIL : 3;
};
```

This is not portable though since it relies on implementation-defined constructs.

Here is a more interesting example:

```
#include <stdint.h>

union RAX_t
{
    uint64_t RAX;
    uint32_t EAX;
    uint16_t AX;
    struct {
        uint8_t AL;
        uint8_t AH;
    };
};
```

(assumes little-endian machine.)

Comment: I found this to also be very helpful. @ybungalobill

Answer (score 0):

No. This is precisely the reason why variables are usually encapsuled with methods.